# How to add product images using script?

Tags: plugins, customization, woocommerce-offtopic

I have few hundred products on woocommerce without images. I am planning to upload images in future. Images have same name as the SKU of product (+.jpg).

Is there a way I could write a script that adds this image as product image and featured image of the SKU = name of this image(-.jpg)?

Comment: This is certainly possible and btw not especially woocommerce specific. Anyhow, you definitely should improve your question, because this way it is clearly a *do my work for me* request, which isn't how [wordpress.se] works. The intention on [wordpress.se] is rather to help you with a problem you already researched and approached. That said, complete this with some groundwork, research and code, and the chances of getting the help you want will get significantly higher.

Comment: +1 for @ialocin and, just for example, what have you tried? What have you find googling for your problem? And regarding the details of your request, do you plan to upload files via FTP or via WordPress media manager?

Comment: Thank You ialocin and G. M.  I am planning to upload files using media Manager . I thought my question as "have anyone done this, if yes, how?" . I was expecting someone to suggest a plugin that might be able to do this(csv import plugin) or a snippet that updates products.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a plugin, if your images names **really** match with product SKUs and you use media uploader to upload the file, you can use **a single function** hooked in [`add_attachment`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/add_attachment) and you are done.

Once it require some work, I'd avoid to upload all the hundreds of images in one "session", probably you can upload sets of 25/50 images per time with no issues...

See comments for further informations on what code does:

```
add_action('add_attachment', function( $attachmentID ) {
  if ( ! class_exists( 'WC_Product' ) ) return; // if no WooCommerce do nothing

  // an attachment was jus saved, first of all get the file name
  $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachmentID, 'full' );
  $filename = pathinfo( $src[0], PATHINFO_FILENAME );

  // now let's see if exits a product with the sku that match filename
  $args = array(
    'meta_key' => '_sku',
    'meta_value' => $filename,
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => '1' // assuming sku is unique get only one post
  );
  $prods = get_posts( $args );
  if ( ! empty($prods) ) {

    // ok we have a match, exists a product having sku that match filename
    $product = array_pop( $prods );

    // set the thumbnail for the product
    set_post_thumbnail( $product, $attachmentID );

    // now "attach" the post to the product setting 'post_parent'
    $attachment = get_post( $attachmentID );
    $attachment->post_parent = $product->ID;
    wp_update_post( $attachment );
  }
});
```

Comment: Just to clarify this is called when an attachment is created, which means that existing images in your media library will not be parsed.

Comment: @codearachnid yep, sure. I did not specify that in the answer because OP explicitly says: *"I am planning to upload images in future"*...

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment to your question, you might take a look at http://www.wpallimport.com they have a woocommerce addon that works pretty well and includes the product image importer. With a custom CSV i'm sure you could wrangle it to import all in one import for you (including the media manager bit).

Now if you are looking to attach existing uploaded media items via a script then it should be as simple as querying your unattached images inspecting their image name (unless you are customizing them) and then doing a meta query sku lookup on `post_type = 'product'` and then run `update_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attachment_id);` with the supplied bits of info. Depending on the amount of images you're looking to parse through + hosting environment this could take a long time or run out of resources/time during execution. So I'd suggest adding a pagination component to throttle your execution process/time down into managable chunks for the environment.