# Where to add my code to auto attach images to existing products

Tags: images, uploads, automatic-updates

I've got this code from an [answer to a previous question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/140089/46066):

```
add_action('add_attachment', function( $attachmentID ) {
  if ( ! class_exists( 'WC_Product' ) ) return; // if no WooCommerce do nothing

  // an attachment was jus saved, first of all get the file name
  $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachmentID, 'full' );
  $filename = pathinfo( $src[0], PATHINFO_FILENAME );

  // now let's see if exits a product with the sku that match filename
  $args = array(
    'meta_key' => '_sku',
    'meta_value' => $filename,
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => '1' // assuming sku is unique get only one post
  );
  $prods = get_posts( $args );
  if ( ! empty($prods) ) {

    // ok we have a match, exists a product having sku that match filename
    $product = array_pop( $prods );

    // set the thumbnail for the product
    set_post_thumbnail( $product, $attachmentID );

    // now "attach" the post to the product setting 'post_parent'
    $attachment = get_post( $attachmentID );
    $attachment->post_parent = $product->ID;
    wp_update_post( $attachment );
  }
});
```

It will solve my problem of matching images to preexisting products when I add them to the media gallery. However, I don't know where in wordpress I need to add it. I'm pretty new to all this.

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, all you need to do is add this to your theme's `functions.php` file.

However, you should also be aware that if you didn't create this theme and you update it, these modifications will be overridden. You can apply them again, but a better method for this (as I've explained a bit more in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/230718/46066)) is to [create a child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).

Alternatively, if this is the only modification you are wanting to make, it might actually be easier to turn the code into a basic plugin. Add it into a blank file, call it `whatever-you-like.php` and put it directly into the `wp-content/plugins/` folder. At the top of the file, after the opening `<?php` tag, add this code:

```
/* Plugin Name: Match Images to Pre-existing Products */
```

Then, on your plugin page, you'll see this plugin come up - and you can activate and de-activate it at will.

The bonus of this second method is you can do this for other modifications you make as well, and then easily activate/deactivate them independently when you require them.

Comment: Creating it as a plugin is a great idea. So simple and won't conflict with anything or give me any problems later on. Thank you very much!